# How to combine two conditions using "and" in list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to return a list of sorted numbers such that odd numbers come first and even numbers come last.

**Example:** `my_sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])` => `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8]`

My solution is returning an empty list.

```
def my_sort(lst):
    sortd_lst = sorted([xfor x in lst if x % 2 == 1 and x % 2 == 0])
    return sortd_lst
```

Comment: How can a number be 1 mod 2 and 0 mod 2

Comment: This has nothing to do with list comprehension. How can `x % 2 == 1 and x % 2 == 0` ever be true, inside or outside a list comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand what your code is doing.

```
sortd_lst = sorted([xfor x in lst if x % 2 == 1 and x % 2 == 0])
```

Your code is checking if a number is **both** even and odd, which is obviously impossible. Thus, you would get an empty list. You need to check these conditions separately.

Here is what you want:

```
sortd_lst = [*sorted(x for x in lst if x % 2 == 1), *sorted(x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0)]
```

This makes two separate sorted lists of odd and even numbers respectively, and then unpacks them into your `sortd_lst`.

Comment: I will do some research on **unpacking**. At one time i had this solution and it was returning nested lists. I strayed to far i guess trying out stuff.

Comment: _"Your code is checking if a number is both even and odd, which is obviously impossible.."_ Hence the OP function returns an empty list.